# Вы когда-нибудь слышали слово «ширдык»?

Tags: этимология, лексика, существительные

Я в последнее время часто слышу слово "ширдык". Решил поискать — как оказалось, такое слово встречается в речи только у жителей республик Калмыкия, Бурятия.

Answer (score 2):

Если отвечать только на *шапочный* вопрос, то все просто: нет, мне слово не встречалось.

В словаре Даля: [ширдык](https://books.google.ee/books?id=9-vJqLDHlN0C&pg=PA417&lpg=PA417&dq=%22%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%BA%22&source=bl&ots=aT2kUOC2yw&sig=ACfU3U0cfQXEo9JyniYCvGQi6IBME1j0eg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOsbjewdj8AhVoQvEDHW9xAYw4FBDoAXoECBQQAw#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%BA%22&f=false), м. стежонный войлок, *забайк*.
В словаре Фасмера: [ширды́к](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/vasmer/51600/%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%BA), "стеганый войлок", забайкальск. (Даль). Из калм. širdǝg — то же, монг. sirideg — то же, откуда и чагат. širdaɣ "чепрак, войлочная подкладка, вид верхней одежды"...

Удивительное дело: где Калмыкия, а где Забайкалье ([см.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C): Забайкальская область, 19 век).
Предполагаю, что слово появилось из "нашественного" монгольского и закрепилось в местностях, где вели кочевой образ жизни. Встречается еще у эвенков и в Астраханской области.

*О Родине запела им домбра,

Кочевники присели у костра,

На землю бросили **ширдык**<sup>1</sup>,

Джомба<sup>2</sup> душистый заварил старик.*
Людмила Мершиева-Скалыго. Лотос

*Старик прискакал к дому, привязал своего коня, вошел в юрту, поздоровался и сел на **ширдык**, расстеленный на полу юрты* (Калмыцкая народная сказка. Умная невестка).

*Наши бабушки войлок катали,

**Ширдыки** будут всем, чтобы сесть,

Чтобы спали спокойно и знали:

Шерсть овечья, как мать, — оберег.*
Этнопедагогическое и этнокультурное наследие в творчестве Михаила Хонинова
**. .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .**
<sup>1</sup> Ширдык — войлок, шитый в два слоя и украшенный орнаментом.
<sup>2</sup> Джомба — калмыцкий чай лучшего приготовления.